# solidity cannot verify ethers.js signed data (signTypedData)

Tags: solidity, metamask, nft, ecdsa

i am using _signTypedData in etherjs to sign and encode a signature out of the data as follows

```
 const domain = {
    name: "og-nft",
    version: "1",
  };
  const types = {
    Nft: [
      { name: "URI", type: "string" },
      { name: "price", type: "uint256" },
    ],
  };

  // The data to sign
  const [voucher, setVoucher] = useState({
    URI: "",
    price: '1',
  });
const signature = await signer._signTypedData(domain, types, voucher);
```

[reference](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Signer-signTypedData)

I am storing the voucher and signature in the mongo database, I have deployed smart contract on hardhat and I am verifying the authenticity of signature by peering out the signer of the voucher using ECDSA.recover

```
function verifyVoucher(NFTVoucher calldata voucher, bytes memory signature)
        public
        view
        returns (address)
    {
        require(voucher.price > 0, "Price must be greater than 0");
      //  require(voucher.tokenId > 0, "Token ID must be greater than 0");
        bytes32 hash = _hash(voucher);
        //string memory hash="";
        return ECDSA.recover(hash, signature);
    }
```

but the result of this is not matching with actual signer. i think I am making some mistake in the hash function above used.

```
0xe8c795f9168269940b31a470ad82e89a453e88b9 signer
0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266 owner
```

below is the hash function.

```
function _hash(NFTVoucher calldata voucher)
        internal
        view
        returns (bytes32)
    {
        return
            _hashTypedDataV4(
                keccak256(
                    abi.encode(
                        keccak256(
                            "Nft(string URI,uint256 price)"
                        ),
                        keccak256(bytes(voucher.URI)),
                        voucher.price
                    )
                )
            );
    }
```

[reference](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/drafts#EIP712-_hashTypedDataV4-bytes32-)

Comment: Did you ever solve your issue? I am having a similar issue: using Metamask signTypedData_v4 to sign a message; I can recover address of signer in the browser but not in solidity. I’ve checked my types many times. I’m running ganache locally to test. Would love to hear how you solved your issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing 2 fields in your domain separator :

- chainId
- verifyingContract

While they are not mandatory as per [EIP-712](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712), the [draft-EIP712.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/cryptography/draft-EIP712.sol) that you seem to be using, is relying on them under the hood when computing the domain separator hash :

```
function _buildDomainSeparator(bytes32 typeHash, bytes32 nameHash, bytes32 versionHash) private view returns (bytes32) {
    return keccak256(abi.encode(typeHash, nameHash, versionHash, block.chainid, address(this)));
    //                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
}
```

So to match draft-EIP712.sol computation you should include them in your domain separator on the client side to generate / sign the exact same data that your contract will verify :

```
 const domain = {
    name: "og-nft",
    version: "1",
    chainId: chainId,
    verifyingContract: contract.address,
  };
```

where chainId  is : `const { chainId, _ } = await provider.getNetwork();` and contract.address is simply the address of your deployed contract.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: thanks for answering sir, i tried putting in the same but dont know again the address came out be wrong , chaidId I got from the signer.provider._network.chainId

Comment: Can you show your smart contract constructor as well as the parameters used for deployment ?

Comment: in the constructor for contract` constructor() ERC721("nftStoreBuilder", "Hash") EIP712("og-nft", "1") {
        _setupRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, _msgSender());
       
    }`    in the frontend ` const domain = {
    name: "og-nft",
    version: "1",
  };
  const types = {
    NFTVoucher: [
      { name: "URI", type: "string" },
      { name: "price", type: "uint256" },
    ],
  };
  ` sorry for late reply

Answer (score 0):

As per the answer that discusses your domain separator, once you have corrected this, you need to put the correct chain ID being used, which if you're using Hardhat may not be 1 - you can obtain it via `await signer.getChainId()`

Once the signature matches what's being validated in Solidity, the signature recovery will succeed.